# Copying a dictionary changes NSMutableArray into NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

So I have this NSMutableDictionary object:

```
pdata=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
       @"",@"pid",
       @"",@"pname",
       [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1],@"ilist",
       nil];
```

And then I copy this object into another object like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *pdataCopy=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:pdata copyItems:TRUE];
```

But once Ive done this, `pdataCopy.ilist` is now an NSArray instead of NSMutableArray.

How can I copy a dictionary object whilst maintaining the mutability of the properies inside it?

Comment: How are you confirming that the copied array is not mutable?

Comment: with `[[pdataCopy objectForKey:"@ilist"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]`

Comment: @DanF: NSLog(@"type: %@", [[pdataCopy objectForKey:@"ilist"] class] returns NSArray. sunkehappy gave u correct answer

Comment: You're getting what you're asking for, more or less.  If you don't ask for the items to be copied you'll get the original mutable array.  Read the NSDictionary spec to see what `copyItems` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can't. You can get a mutable array by

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [pdataCopy.ilist mutableCopy]
```

Comment: Hi Jimmery, I think it will not be easy to do it. No one want to maintain too complicated code. So KISS.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Don't specify `copyItems:YES`
2. Scan through the dictionary after copying and replace NSArrays with NSMutableArrays (using `mutableCopy`) as desired.
3. Create your own subclass of NSMutableArray that responds to `copyWithZone` by producing a mutable copy of itself (and use objects of that class in your dictionary).

Comment: option 2 it is! why does objective-c insist on changing your mutable objects into immutable objects?! gah!

Comment: @Jimmery - It doesn't "insist" on anything.  It's just that NSMutableArray inherits copyWithZone from NSArray, and so an NSArray is returned.  (Are you sure you need to copy the arrays?)